# Override based on properties on an HTMLElement

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to make a function which will take an `HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLSelectElement` and will derive a value based on its properties. The implementation seemed fairly simple to begin with:

```
function deriveValue(element: HTMLInputElement) {
  switch (element.type) {
    case 'number':
      return element.valueAsNumber;
    default:
      return element.value;
  }
}
```

Things started to get a bit weird here as my signature became:

```
function deriveValue(element: HTMLInputElement): string | number;
```

When I used it like so, it showed the value of `t` as being `number | string`

```
const element = document.createElement('input');
element.type = 'number';
deriveValue(element) // number | string
```

I reached to make an overload, but it didn't seem to work as I wanted:

```
function deriveValue(element: HTMLInputElement & { type: 'number' }): number;
function deriveValue(element: HTMLInputElement): string;
function deriveValue(element: HTMLInputElement) {
  switch (element.type) {
    case 'number':
      return element.valueAsNumber;
    default:
      return element.value;
  }
}
```

This still doesn't work. I think the problem might derive from `type` being defined as `string` on these elements

Is it possible to make overrides like this on top of an HTMLElement?